# Does large query result for a query in ES index increases the latency

Tags: elasticsearch, latency

In an API call we are making a query to ES index to get desired results . Our query is such that we get more than 15k docs as a result from ES index . To get those results we are making multiple recursive calls to Elastic search index(for pagination) in the same API call . Does this large number of query result size increase latency of our ES call.

Comment: what is your query?

Comment: how do you implement pagination? did you use scroll API?

Comment: Yes @hamid bayat

Comment: My query is such that I am applying an array of filters and in that filters I have some term filters and a terms(array) filter.

Comment: I think there will no serious latency if you use under 15 parallel recursive calls. scroll api is very robust and efficient to collect large portion of docs.

Comment: Actually I have tested it out with the data and it's taking around 1s in every subsequent call and there are 5-6 such calls one after the other , so they are taking 5-6s to complete the query .

Comment: 5-6 seconds to fetch 15k documents? that is very good response time.

Comment: Oh really ?? Umm I was expecting it to be less than a second

Comment: elasticsearch is search engine and designed to show top result.

Answer (score 0):

That depends to many parameters such as number of shards and their replication, The queries run parallel in your shards regardless of each other in inverted index tables on the other hand having too many shards can makes your system to overhead, In brief I guess the best approach for reducing your latency is the balancing number of queries, Shards and documents together. Please also note that having too many queries on few(1-3) shards will obviously increase the latency regardless of amount of your data.

The following [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/improving-response-latency-in-elasticsearch-with-adaptive-replica-selection) may helps.